# Python: Writing peoples scores to individual lines

Tags: python

I have a task where I need to record peoples scores in a text file. My Idea was to set it out like this:

```
Jon: 4, 1, 3
Simon: 1, 3, 6
```

This has the name they inputted along with their 3 last scores (Only 3 should be recorded).

Now for my question; Can anyone point me in the right direction to do this? Im not asking for you to write my code for me, Im simply asking for some tips.
Thanks.

Edit: Im guessing it would look something like this: I dont know how I'd add scores after their first though like above.

```
def File():
    score = str(Name) + ": " + str(correct)
    File = open('Test.txt', 'w+')
    File.write(score)
    File.close()

Name = input("Name: ")
correct = input("Number: ")
File()
```

Comment: Just because you say you're not asking for code, doesn't mean you're not. Show us what you've tried and where you're having an issue.

Comment: How are you getting all peoples' scores as your input? What have you already tried?

Comment: You could try pandas `to_csv()` function. It'll be pretty easy that way and you could basically follow their tutorial on how to do it

Comment: Why would you invent your own format? Use CSV or XML or JSON or Python pickle ...  (or SQLITE).

Comment: You need to be looping through the people somehow.  The code you have now would write one score for one person.

Answer (score 1):

You could use pandas `to_csv()` function and store your data in a dictionary. It will be much easier than creating your own format.

```
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
import pandas as pd

def tfile(names):
    df = DataFrame(data = names, columns = names.keys())   
    with open('directory','w') as f:
        f.write(df.to_string(index=False, header=True))

names = {}
for i in xrange(num_people):
    name = input('Name: ')
    if name not in names:
        names[name] = []
    for j in xrange(3):
        score = input('Score: ')
        names[name].append(score)
tfile(names)

 Simon  Jon
     1    4
     3    1
     6    3
```

This should meet your text requirement now. It converts it to a string and then writes the string to the .txt file. If you need to read it back in you can use pandas `read_table()`. Here's a [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#writing-a-formatted-string) if you want to read about it.

Comment: Theres limitations on the task, it has to be in a .txt file :/

Comment: @Csarg Updated to meet the .txt requirement

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not asking for the exact code, here is an idea and some pointers

1. Collect the last three scores per person in a list variable called last_three
2. do something like:

   ```
   ",".join(last_three) #this gives you the format 4,1,3 etc
   ```
3. write to file an entry such as

   ```
   name + ":" + ",".join(last_three)
   ```
4. You'll need to do this for each "line" you process
5. I'd recommend using with clause to open the file in write mode and process your data (as opposed to just an "open" clause) since with handles try/except/finally problems of opening/closing file handles...So...

   ```
   with open(my_file_path, "w") as f:
       for x in my_formatted_data:
          #assuming x is a list of two elements name and last_three elems (example: [Harry, [1,4,5]])
          name, last_three = x
          f.write(name + ":" + ",".join(last_three))
          f.write("\n")# a new line
   ```

   6. In this way you don't really need to open/close file as with clause takes care of it for you

Comment: Exactly the type of thing I was looking for- I'll play around with this and get back to you.